# Inverse lookup table

Tags: matlab, binary

This is a follow up question from a previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544456/faster-version-of-dec2bin-function-for-converting-many-elements). Now I have a bit which I have spread it into 8 bits. I have use Amro's solution to spread the bit to 8 bits. Now I want an inverse way to convert the 8bits back to the single bit.

I have only managed to implement the inverse using for loop which take alot of time in the application.

Is there a faster way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the solution I suggested last time, lets say you have a matrix N-by-8 of these 'bits' where each row represent one 8-bit binary number. To convert to decimal in a vectorized way, its as simple as:

```
» M = randi([0 1], [5 8])      %# 5 random 8-bit numbers
M =
     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     1
     0     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     1
     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     0
     1     0     0     1     0     1     1     0
» d = bin2dec( num2str(M) )
d =
   171
   110
   219
   134
   150
```

An alternative solution:

```
d = sum( bsxfun(@times, M, power(2,7:-1:0)), 2)
```

Comment: The bit is no longer decimal, it is just 0 or 1, it is really just bit. Meaning the 8 bits is just representing is it a 0 or 1. So my inverse lookup table only have 2 entries.

Comment: well If i'm getting this right, you just look at the rightmost column since the others will be all zeros, ie `d = M(:,8)`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Well, no. I'm doing CDMA Spreading for example, 01101100 is a spread code and it represent bit 0 and the complement of the spread code 10010011 represent bit 1. So now I have a M x 8 matrix, the whole matrix just comprise the spread code and its complement. Now I just want to despread it by turning the 8 bits back into the bit it represent. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: ok, then cant you differentiate between the two codes simply by looking at any one column (since the codes are complement to each other)?