# Permutations of 0s and 1s with Recursion

Tags: matlab, recursion, binary, permutation

I am trying to write all the 6-bit permutations of 0s and 1s using recursion (i.e., [0 0 0 0 0 1], [0 0 0 0 1 0], [0 0 0 0 1 1], [0 0 0 1 0 0], ... [1 1 1 1 1 1]). I'm following a tip I got from [Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100526070957AAFMkSh) I've got the following but it just doesn't go all the way to the end and there are duplicate entries.

```
function [c] = myIEEEBaby_all_decimals(h, n)

% n: number of characters more to add

if n == 0
   converter(h);
   return 
end

in1 = [h 1];
in2 = [h 0];

converter(in1);
converter(in2);

if length(h) < n
    myIEEEBaby_all_decimals([in1], n-1)
    myIEEEBaby_all_decimals([in2], n-1)
end

end

function [d] = converter(IEEE)
% convert custom IEEE representation to decimal

IEEE = [zeros(1,6-length(IEEE)), IEEE];

s = IEEE(1);

characteristic = IEEE([2,3]);
k = find(fliplr(characteristic)) - 1;
c = sum(2.^k);

fraction = IEEE([4:6]);
f = sum(2.^-(find(fliplr(fraction))));

d = (-1)^s*2^(c-1)*(1+f);

disp([num2str(IEEE),' : ', num2str(d)]);

end
```

The output (MATLAB) is just:

```
>> myIEEEBaby_all_decimals([],6)
0  0  0  0  0  1 : 0.75
0  0  0  0  0  0 : 0.5
0  0  0  0  1  1 : 0.875
0  0  0  0  1  0 : 0.625
0  0  0  1  1  1 : 0.9375
0  0  0  1  1  0 : 0.6875
0  0  1  1  1  1 : 1.875
0  0  1  1  1  0 : 1.375
0  0  1  1  0  1 : 1.625
0  0  1  1  0  0 : 1.125
0  0  0  1  0  1 : 0.8125
0  0  0  1  0  0 : 0.5625
0  0  1  0  1  1 : 1.75
0  0  1  0  1  0 : 1.25
0  0  1  0  0  1 : 1.5
0  0  1  0  0  0 : 1
0  0  0  0  0  1 : 0.75
0  0  0  0  0  0 : 0.5
0  0  0  0  1  1 : 0.875
0  0  0  0  1  0 : 0.625
0  0  0  1  1  1 : 0.9375
0  0  0  1  1  0 : 0.6875
0  0  0  1  0  1 : 0.8125
0  0  0  1  0  0 : 0.5625
0  0  0  0  0  1 : 0.75
0  0  0  0  0  0 : 0.5
0  0  0  0  1  1 : 0.875
0  0  0  0  1  0 : 0.625
0  0  0  0  0  1 : 0.75
0  0  0  0  0  0 : 0.5
```

Comment: That's not what "permutation" means: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate from 0 to 2<sup>6</sup>-1 and call Matlab's [`dec2bin(...)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dec2bin.html) function. You could pad the result with zero's using [`sprintf(...)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html).

Comment: Ah, thanks! That's so much easier than what I thought I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compute every possible value of a 6-bit number, there are much more efficient ways to do it than using recursion. Using the function [DEC2BIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dec2bin.html) is one option, but [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544456/faster-version-of-dec2bin-function-for-converting-many-elements) shows that implementations using the function [BITGET](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bitget.html) or indexing via a look-up table are much faster. For example, here's one possible solution:

```
allperms = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(b) {bitget((0:2^6-1).',b)},6:-1:1));
```

Then you can apply your `converter` function to the result on a row-wise basis:

```
converter = @(b) (1-2.*b(:,1)).*...             %# The sign contribution
            2.^(b(:,2:3)*[2; 1] - 1).*...       %# The exponent contribution
            (1 + b(:,4:6)*[0.125; 0.25; 0.5]);  %# The fraction contribution
values = converter(allperms);
```

And you can display the results as follows:

```
>> disp(sprintf('%d %d %d %d %d %d : %f\n',[allperms values].'))
0 0 0 0 0 0 : 0.500000
0 0 0 0 0 1 : 0.750000
0 0 0 0 1 0 : 0.625000
0 0 0 0 1 1 : 0.875000
0 0 0 1 0 0 : 0.562500
0 0 0 1 0 1 : 0.812500
0 0 0 1 1 0 : 0.687500
0 0 0 1 1 1 : 0.937500
0 0 1 0 0 0 : 1.000000
0 0 1 0 0 1 : 1.500000
0 0 1 0 1 0 : 1.250000
0 0 1 0 1 1 : 1.750000
0 0 1 1 0 0 : 1.125000
0 0 1 1 0 1 : 1.625000
0 0 1 1 1 0 : 1.375000
0 0 1 1 1 1 : 1.875000
0 1 0 0 0 0 : 2.000000
0 1 0 0 0 1 : 3.000000
0 1 0 0 1 0 : 2.500000
0 1 0 0 1 1 : 3.500000
0 1 0 1 0 0 : 2.250000
0 1 0 1 0 1 : 3.250000
0 1 0 1 1 0 : 2.750000
0 1 0 1 1 1 : 3.750000
0 1 1 0 0 0 : 4.000000
0 1 1 0 0 1 : 6.000000
0 1 1 0 1 0 : 5.000000
0 1 1 0 1 1 : 7.000000
0 1 1 1 0 0 : 4.500000
0 1 1 1 0 1 : 6.500000
0 1 1 1 1 0 : 5.500000
0 1 1 1 1 1 : 7.500000
1 0 0 0 0 0 : -0.500000
1 0 0 0 0 1 : -0.750000
1 0 0 0 1 0 : -0.625000
1 0 0 0 1 1 : -0.875000
1 0 0 1 0 0 : -0.562500
1 0 0 1 0 1 : -0.812500
1 0 0 1 1 0 : -0.687500
1 0 0 1 1 1 : -0.937500
1 0 1 0 0 0 : -1.000000
1 0 1 0 0 1 : -1.500000
1 0 1 0 1 0 : -1.250000
1 0 1 0 1 1 : -1.750000
1 0 1 1 0 0 : -1.125000
1 0 1 1 0 1 : -1.625000
1 0 1 1 1 0 : -1.375000
1 0 1 1 1 1 : -1.875000
1 1 0 0 0 0 : -2.000000
1 1 0 0 0 1 : -3.000000
1 1 0 0 1 0 : -2.500000
1 1 0 0 1 1 : -3.500000
1 1 0 1 0 0 : -2.250000
1 1 0 1 0 1 : -3.250000
1 1 0 1 1 0 : -2.750000
1 1 0 1 1 1 : -3.750000
1 1 1 0 0 0 : -4.000000
1 1 1 0 0 1 : -6.000000
1 1 1 0 1 0 : -5.000000
1 1 1 0 1 1 : -7.000000
1 1 1 1 0 0 : -4.500000
1 1 1 1 0 1 : -6.500000
1 1 1 1 1 0 : -5.500000
1 1 1 1 1 1 : -7.500000
```

Comment: Actually the vectorized `dec2bin` seems to be faster than the `bitget` solution as presented here. Try: `x = dec2bin(1:2^6-1); allperms = x-'0';`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write all permutations in a simple way, use `dec2bin` to get the binary values like @Bart recommended.

However, this kind of operation can often be done significantly more efficient if you use vectorization.

So instead of looping over all values and obtaining the results 1 by one, simply do this:

```
x = dec2bin(1:2^6-1);
```

If you want the output to be a matrix, also do this:

```
x = x - '0';
```