# Convert Decimal to Binary Vector

Tags: matlab, binary

I need to convert a Decimal Number to a Binary Vector

For example, Something like this:

```
  length=de2bi(length_field,16);
```

Unfortunately, because of licensing, I cannot use this command. Is there any quick short technique for converting binary to a vector.

Here is what I am looking for,

```
If 
Data=12;
Bin_Vec=Binary_To_Vector(Data,6) should return me
Bin_Vec=[0 0 1 1 0 0]
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal to binary as double type array, not string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274368/decimal-to-binary-as-double-type-array-not-string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution that is reasonably fast:

```
function out = binary2vector(data,nBits)

powOf2 = 2.^[0:nBits-1];

%# do a tiny bit of error-checking
if data > sum(powOf2)
   error('not enough bits to represent the data')
end

out = false(1,nBits);

ct = nBits;

while data>0
if data >= powOf2(ct)
data = data-powOf2(ct);
out(ct) = true;
end
ct = ct - 1;
end
```

To use:

```
out = binary2vector(12,6)
out =
     0     0     1     1     0     0

out = binary2vector(22,6)
out =
     0     1     1     0     1     0
```

Comment: @kirancshet: you're welcome. I added a little bit of input testing to avoid an infinite loop.

Answer (score 19):

You mention not being able to use the function [`de2bi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/comm/ref/de2bi.html), which is likely because it is a function in the [Communications System Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/communications/) and you don't have a license for it. Luckily, there are two other functions that you can use that are part of the core MATLAB toolbox: [BITGET](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bitget.html) and [DEC2BIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dec2bin.html). I generally lean towards using BITGET since [DEC2BIN can be significantly slower when converting many values at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544456/faster-version-of-dec2bin-function-for-converting-many-elements). Here's how you would use BITGET:

```
>> Data = 12;                  %# A decimal number
>> Bin_Vec = bitget(Data,1:6)  %# Get the values for bits 1 through 6

Bin_Vec =

     0     0     1     1     0     0
```

Comment: Oh, nice! +1 for knowing Matlab well :). Note that I thought the author couldn't use `dec2bin` and had just mistyped. I didn't even know that `de2bi` actually exists.

Comment: +1 for simple to use! However, note many will want to call `fliplr(bitget(Data,1:6))` to get the numbers in the 'correct' order. Depends on usage of course (:

Answer (score 10):

A single call to Matlab's built-in function `dec2bin` can achieve this:

```
binVec = dec2bin(data, nBits)-'0'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not aware that dec2bin could be used to get a binary vector like this.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using this for IEEE 802.11 SIGNAL field? I noticed "length_field" and "16".
Anyway here's how I do it.

```
    function [Ibase2]= Convert10to2(Ibase10,n)

    % Convert the integral part by successive divisions by 2
    Ibase2=[];


    if (Ibase10~=0)

    while (Ibase10>0)

    q=fix(Ibase10/2);
    r=Ibase10-2*q;
    Ibase2=[r Ibase2];
    Ibase10=q;
    end


    else
    Ibase2=0;
    end

    o = length(Ibase2);
    % append redundant zeros
    Ibase2 = [zeros(1,n-o) Ibase2];
```